# which meta tags are used by google and bing search

Tags: search, seo, search-engine, meta

I am working on an asp.net mvc web application, and i am using a web templete that have the following metadata:-

```
<html>
<head>   

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="description" content="Your description">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Your keywords">
    <meta name="author" content="My web Site">
    <title>Edama - @ViewBag.Title  </title>
```

now i have the following questions:-

- will these meta tags be treated the same inside google & bing search engines?
- what is the purpose for providing  `content="telephone=no"` how it will be understood by google and bing search engines ?
- final question. on some website when i search for them , i got links such as About, contact, etc.. so how i can provide these info to search engines ?

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too broad and about SEO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google has a list of meta tags they understand :

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/79812?hl=en

Comment: is there a similar list for bing ?

Comment: Not that I know of, though I think the meta tags are generally the same.